# Whats a better way to open man pages?

Tags: ide, developer-tools, manpage

I'm always forgetting to read `man` pages for unix commands during my work as a developer. I don't like the clunky `man` page interface and it's hard to get to the parts I need like a useful example of how to use the command.

Is there a better way? My chosen IDE is PHPStorm in case that is relevant to your answer. My daily OS is OSX 10.8.5

Comment: Have you attempted using `info` instead?

Comment: phpStorm is primarily for PHP and Javascript programming. It's not for writing C or shell scripts, so I wouldn't expect it to provide a man page utility. I think there are GUI interfaces to man available for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe `|` the output of a command (Like a man page) to your IDE. I use Sublime, so for me, to read the man page for ls, I would do...

```
man ls | sublime
```

If for some reason your IDE can't do that, you can just write the output to a .txt file and read it there using any of the "write" operators. [Here's an example of those](https://askubuntu.com/a/420983).